# my php form keeps duplicating rows in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

Hi im trying to create a subscribe to mailing list widget. its kind of working but keeps adding a blank row after every insert. I would like to jsut be able to let users add their name and email address to 2 inputs and click submit, then the details should be saved into the database, avoiding spam and duplications etc.

here is where am at so far hopefully someone could give a few pointers im very new to php so any help is appreciated thanks!

```
  <?php
    // Connect to server and select database.
    //mysql_connect("$subsc_hostname", "$subsc_username", "$subsc_password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    //mysql_select_db("$subsc_database")or die("cannot select DB");
    $mysqlconn=  new PDO('mysql:dbname=' .$subsc_database . ';host=' . $subsc_hostname,  $subsc_username,  $subsc_password);

    $subsc_name = $_POST['sub_FullName'];
    $subsc_email = $_POST['sub_EmailAddress'];

    // Insert data into mysql 
    $sql="INSERT INTO subscribers(subsc_name, subsc_email)VALUES('$subsc_name', '$subsc_email')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // close connection 
    mysql_close();

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Full Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_FullName" />
    <br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_EmailAddress" />

        <div class="pull-right">
            <input  type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Before checking if the user entered an correct email address, you should check if the user didn't try to perform an SQL injection to your database. Just saying...

Comment: sql="`INSERT INTO subscribers VALUES('$subsc_name', '$subsc_email');` would work as well, provided there are only two items in the table. Most tables have a primary (index).

Comment: Sidenote: Both `ereg` and `mysql_*` are deprecated functions. Come back into the 21st century.

Comment: Like Biapy said, your `}` should include the actual SQL, otherwise it's will `INSERT INTO` regardless. Also, look into PDO instead of MySQL. Like Fred was mentioning, its depreciated (not to mention full of potential security nightmares)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to move the last `}` in your file:

```
    } else {
    mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'><h4>Subscribed!</h4><p>Thanks $contact_name,<br /><br />you will start receiving emails  via $contact_email very soon.</div>"; 

// FROM HERE

    // Insert data into mysql 
    $sql="INSERT INTO subscribers(subsc_name, subsc_email)VALUES('$subsc_name', '$subsc_email')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

// TO HERE
    }
```

To add to the comments to your question, you may want to take a look at lightweight frameworks like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) and to database abstraction layers, like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/). Using such tools, you greatly reduce the risks of SQL injections and you don't need to code every single user provided data control by hand.

Comment: thanks for advice so far everybody so i have stripped back a bit and attempted using PDO but could use a few pointers it worked with my old connection string?

Comment: You may take a look at mysqli_prepare : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php . Using the query preparation protect from SQL injection. Note that you must update your code to use mysqli functions instead of old mysql functions. mysqli is the newest MySQL implementation for PHP, and is safe to use on modern systems.